# Is there a way to determine degree centrality of an apache age graph

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Is there a way to determine the degree centrality of a graph made with apache age to determine the importance of the nodes? I need to analyze the influence of the nodes in the following graph:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE connections (
    person_id INTEGER REFERENCES people(id),
    friend_id INTEGER REFERENCES people(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id, friend_id)
);
```

and here is the sample data

```
-- People
INSERT INTO people (name) VALUES
('Alice'),
('Bob'),
('Charlie'),
('David'),
('Eve');

-- Connections
INSERT INTO connections (person_id, friend_id) VALUES
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(3, 4),
(4, 5);
```

I need guidance about how to write cypher query to determine degree centrality and how to sort the nodes based on their influence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to create this graph in Apache AGE, you can use the following cypher query:

```
SELECT create_graph('graph');
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    CREATE (:people {name: 'Alice'}), (:people {name: 'Bob'}), (:people {name: 'Charlie'}), (:people {name: 'David'}), (:people {name: 'Eve'})
$$) AS (n agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (a:people), (b:people)
    WHERE a.name = 'Alice' AND (b.name = 'Bob' OR b.name = 'Charlie')
    CREATE (a)-[e:friend]->(b)
    RETURN e
$$) AS (v agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (a:people), (b:people)
    WHERE a.name = 'Bob' AND (b.name = 'Charlie' OR b.name = 'David')
    CREATE (a)-[e:friend]->(b)
    RETURN e
$$) AS (v agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (a:people), (b:people)
    WHERE a.name = 'Charlie' AND b.name = 'David'
    CREATE (a)-[e:friend]->(b)
    RETURN e
$$) AS (v agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (a:people), (b:people)
    WHERE a.name = 'David' AND b.name = 'Eve'
    CREATE (a)-[e:friend]->(b)
    RETURN e
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

To get the degree centrality of the graph (how many connections a node has) and order by it, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (v:people)-[r:friend]-(w:people)
    RETURN v.name, count(r)
    ORDER BY count(r) DESC
$$) AS (name agtype, influence agtype);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query will give you the required degree centrality and the result will be sorted in descending order

```
MATCH (p:people)-[r:connections]-()
RETURN p.name, degree(r) as centrality_det
ORDER BY centrality_det DESC
```

Comment: Where is `degree` documented? It’s not in the AGE docs…

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the degree centrality of nodes and sort them based on their influence by following this approach:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
    MATCH (v:people)-[r:friend]-(w:people)
    WITH v.name AS name, count(r) AS friends
    ORDER BY count(r) DESC                                                                                                                              
    RETURN name, friends
$$) AS (name agtype, influence agtype);
```

It will return:

```
   name    | influence
-----------+-----------
 "Bob"     | 3
 "Charlie" | 3
 "David"   | 3
 "Alice"   | 2
 "Eve"     | 1
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The degree of centrality of the nodes if a graph can be calculated using this query:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n.name AS node, size((n)-[]-()) AS degree_centrality
ORDER BY degree_centrality DESC;
```

The above query will return a list of nodes accompanied by their degree of centrality values sorted in the descending order.

Comment: Nowhere in the docs does it say that `size` takes a pattern in AGE… Have you again confused Neo4j for AGE?